# How to get a filed from self.data in model_formset_factory in clean method

Tags: python, django, forms, models

I am using `modelformset_factory` to edit multiple images on my interface. 
I have following fields in each image.

```
Name
User
City
```

I have allowed user to select new user that is currently not in the system, (for that case I should get a text "Jack" in my 
`def clean_user(self)` instead of `ID`.

But using `model_formseta_factory`, I am getting some wired names in my self.data. and when I try to get self.data.get('user'), I get nothing, obviously there is no key with this name, 
the key is formed like `form_0_user` etc.

```
fields = ['city', 'name']
```

note, i do not have user in my fields. if I do, it fails the validation.

```
def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    data['name'] = data.get('name', '').strip()
    return data
```

Works fine

```
pic_credits = self.data.get('user')
```

This does not.

```
pic_credits = self.data.get('form-0-name')
```

This works fine too.

Please help.

Comment: Anyone please can anyone help me out??

Comment: did u find the solution yet?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `self.data` instead of `self.cleaned_data`, you can construct the "composite prefix" using the fields `auto_id` and `prefix` (or at least when the form has been instanced by a formset).

See `_construct_form()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/_modules/django/forms/formsets/

Your method will look like this:

```
def clean(self):
    # ...

    form_prefix_and_autoid = "%s-%d-" % (self.prefix, self.auto_id)
    pic_credits = self.data.get(form_prefix_and_autoid + 'name')         

    # ...
```

---

**Update:**

A lot simpler is calling the method `self.add_prefix`

```
    pic_credits = self.data.get(self.add_prefix('name'))
```

Comment: The update made everything work excellent. Very pythonic as well, thanks!